# Footer is displaying in middle of screen instead of bottom in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

In IE11, footer is displayed at middle of screen rather than on bottom. I am using below CSS which was working file until we upgraded the browser to IE11.

```
#footer {
    clear: both; 
    height:45px; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    border: none; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Note:- My page has a Tab views & we are using Layout template in MVC. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: You will need to include much more code. Preferably make a demo using stack snippets or another tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your CSS. Based on experience, the only issue I can foresee, is that your footer has a parent element with the property `position: relative;`

This causes the "absolute" positioning to be relative to the parent and not the window itself.

Also, you probably don't `clear:both;`. If you have floating elements inside footer, just add `overflow: auto;` and that will clear your floats!

Answer (score -1):

It may now be less relevant as IE seems to be less and less popular, but the only thing IE properly recognizes as far as vertical positioning is concerned is div. So what seems to have helped in my case is brute-forcing all elements, including the footer, into its own div:

```
<div style={{position: "sticky", top: "0px", zIndex: "10"}} >
    <Nav />
</div>
<div>
    <C {...props} {...cProps} />
</div>
<div style={{marginTop: "20px"}}>
    <Footer />
</div>
```